# Regex to find a particular pattern in Excel

Tags: regex, excel, excel-formula

This is the text in cell **H1**

```
<a class="stop-propagation" href="javascript:void(0);" data-link="/propertyDetails/poiOnMap.html?lat=19.2412011&amp;longt=73.1290596&amp;projectOrProp=Project&amp;city=Thane&amp;includeJs=y&amp;type=poiMap2017&amp;address=Thane, Maharashtra" id="map_link_27696295" onclick="stopPage=true; showPhotoMap('/propertyDetails/poiOnMap.html?lat=19.2412011&amp;longt=73.1290596&amp;projectOrProp=Project&amp;city=Thane&amp;includeJs=y&amp;type=poiMap2017&amp;address=Thane, Maharashtra');" style="outline: 1px solid blue;"><span class="icoMap"></span>Map</a>
```

From above cell I'm trying to extract element of 1st occurrence of  **lat and longt**

This is what I have tried

```
=IF(LEFT(H1,2)="lat=",SUBSTITUTE(H1,"lat=",""),IF(RIGHT(H1,2)="lat=",SUBSTITUTE(H1,"lat=",""),H1))
```

But it doesn't gives me proper output.

This is what I Expect

```
lat=19.2412011
longt=73.1290596
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Just matching "lat=" if that would have succeeded , would have tried for "longt=" as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the *lat=19.2412011*,

```
=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(H1,1,FIND("?",H1),TEXT(,)),"&amp;",REPT(" ",LEN(H1))), LEN(H1)))
```

For the *longt=73.1290596*,

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(H1,1,FIND("?",H1),TEXT(,)),"&amp;",REPT(" ",LEN(H1))), LEN(H1), LEN(H1)))
```

For the two together in a single cell with a line feed,

```
=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(H1,1,FIND("?",H1),TEXT(,)),"&amp;",REPT(" ",LEN(H1))),LEN(H1)))&CHAR(10)&TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(H1,1,FIND("?",H1),TEXT(,)),"&amp;",REPT(" ",LEN(H1))),LEN(H1),LEN(H1)))
```

[image]

Comment: that was brilliant... worked like a charm ,saved me for the day!!! ...Thanks a ton!!!